# Grails 2.x - How to keep file extension for one URL mapping?

Tags: grails

In my Grails application, I have a URL mapping like:

`/section/$title/object/$id`

IDs are not a number. They are strings which can contain `.`. Grails is removing everything after the first `.`, so that if I have `/section/books/object/affx.1.2.10`, the controller method is only receiving `affx`.

I am aware that file extension processing can be turned off globally, but that is not what I want. I need to keep the full ID string **ONLY** for this URL. How can I either do that for this one URL mapping, or add some logic to when Grails will remove file extensions?

Answer (score 0):

Add constraints section to your url-mapping for example:

```
"/test/$id"(controller: test, action: 'index') {
    constraints {
        id(matches: /.+/)
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried it and the controller method still only receives `affx`.

Comment: Did you try to extend regexp to extort dots in $id? From grails 2.3 you can also try: `"/$controller/$action?/$id?(.${format})?"` and get rest of it in $format variable.